# Google Apps Script close UI App after execution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that imports data from a csv file after inserting the name of the file via a UI. It all works 100%, the file is located and the data is imported as expected. However, the app does not close and the pop-up UI remains active on the screen.

My script is as follows:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [
                     {name: "Import Employee Base Data", functionName: "importFromBaseCSV"},
                    ];
  ss.addMenu("User Functions", menuEntries);
}

//IMPORT BASE DATA FROM CSV

function importFromBaseCSV() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var importBaseDataApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Import BASE Data').setHeight(120).setWidth(350);

  var importBaseDataGrid = importBaseDataApp.createGrid(3, 2);
  importBaseDataGrid.setWidget(0, 0, importBaseDataApp.createLabel('Enter the File Date: '));
  importBaseDataGrid.setWidget(0, 1, importBaseDataApp.createTextBox().setName('baseDataFilename').setFocus(true).setWidth(150));
  importBaseDataGrid.setWidget(1, 0, importBaseDataApp.createLabel('e.g. 23092013'));
  importBaseDataGrid.setWidget(2, 0, importBaseDataApp.createLabel(''));

  var importBaseDataPanel = importBaseDataApp.createVerticalPanel();
  importBaseDataPanel.add(importBaseDataGrid);

  var importButton = importBaseDataApp.createButton('Import');
  var importHandler = importBaseDataApp.createServerHandler('importBaseData');
  importHandler.addCallbackElement(importBaseDataGrid);
  importButton.addClickHandler(importHandler);

  importBaseDataPanel.add(importButton);
  importBaseDataApp.add(importBaseDataPanel);
  ss.show(importBaseDataApp);

 }   

function importBaseData(e){

  var fileName = "C BS BASE " + e.parameter.baseDataFilename + ".csv";
  var files = DocsList.getFiles();
  var csvFile = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].getName() == fileName) {
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString();
      break;
    }
  }
  var csvData = CSVToArray(csvFile, ",");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Imported Base Data");
  for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
  }
}

// This will parse a delimited string into an array of
// arrays. The default delimiter is the comma, but this
// can be overriden in the second argument.

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){
  // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to comma.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

      // Quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

      // Standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );


  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;


  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }


    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }


    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("...Completed", "Import Employee Base Data:", 3);

  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );

  var importBaseDataApp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  importBaseDataApp.close();
  return importBaseDataApp;

}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at it quickly, but try this. I moved the "Toast" and "Close" into the function that is called by the clickHandler. You want to control the Ui's in their calling function, its much smoother.  Sometimes you might get lucky and they close or update calling them in another called function.

```
function importBaseData(e){

  var fileName = "C BS BASE " + e.parameter.baseDataFilename + ".csv";
  var files = DocsList.getFiles();
  var csvFile = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].getName() == fileName) {
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString();
      break;
    }
  }
  var csvData = CSVToArray(csvFile, ",");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Imported Base Data");
  for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("...Completed", "Import Employee Base Data:", 3);

  var importBaseDataApp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  importBaseDataApp.close();
  return importBaseDataApp;
}

// This will parse a delimited string into an array of
// arrays. The default delimiter is the comma, but this
// can be overriden in the second argument.

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){
  // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to comma.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

      // Quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

      // Standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );


  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;


  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }


    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }


    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }
  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That worked and of course makes sense. Much obliged for the help.